# Docker-Compose won't launch ros node, but Docker run will

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a strange issue running a ROS Melodic node inside a Docker container.

Within the container I want to launch `row_follower.launch` inside the `navvy_row` package. If I run the container with a command argument, `docker run --rm -it --net host navvy_row roslaunch navvy_row row_follower.launch`, the node starts without issue:

```
... logging to /root/.ros/log/a5064c4a-e3e2-11eb-b627-48b02d0788d9/roslaunch-nanoboi-235.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://nanoboi:45713/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /ransac_row_followerv2/LeftRightThreshold: 0.8
 * /ransac_row_followerv2/PPMultiplier: 5
...
```

However if I try the same using `docker-compose` and the below entry:

```
  navvy_row:
    container_name: navvy_row
    image: navvy_row
    build: navvy_row/
    network_mode: host
    command: roslaunch navvy_row row_follower.launch
```

I get no output past the echo from /ros_entrypoint.sh. I know the workspace is sourced correctly because replacing the command: with `rospack find navvy_row` returns the location as expected.

Attaching to the container and launching the launchfile starts as expected, but then the original docker-compose logs show an error because two nodes were registered with the same name, starts loading the new node and then the whole container exits.

```
navvy_row    | [ WARN] [1626185169.544579230]: Shutdown request received.
navvy_row    | [ WARN] [1626185169.544793054]: Reason given for shutdown: [[/ransac_row_followerv2] Reason: new node registered with same name]
navvy_row    | [ INFO] [1626185126.115699876]: Starting ransac row node
navvy_row    | [ INFO] [1626185126.259093209]: Finished Setup, Starting Spinning
...
```

If I don't start `roscore` on the host before trying to launch the container, if it's the only container the same thing happens (nothing).

If I have another ros1 container running it seems to sometimes get further but always results in an error from one of the containers:

```
RLException: run_id on parameter server does not match declared run_id: 13e8b156-e3e4-11eb-b345-48b02d0788d9 vs 13e26936-e3e4-11eb-8394-48b02d0788d9
```

I've run out of ideas on how to fix this, any help much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382368/docker-compose-won%27t-launch-ros-node,-but-docker-run-will/) by [XDGFX](https://answers.ros.org/users/77679/xdgfx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-07-13**:
I'm afraid there are things you haven't described about your environment. First sharing the content of `.launch` file helps.

> If I don't start `roscore` on the host before trying to launch the container,

What is this? Is running `roscore` aside from the `docker-compose` process in question a requirement?

**Comment by [XDGFX](https://answers.ros.org/users/77679/xdgfx/) on 2021-07-14**:
This is the contents of the .launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <node pkg="navvy_row" name="ransac_row_followerv2" type="ransac_row_followerv2" output="screen">
      <param name="maxRowRatio" value="0.9" /> <!-- Top limit of row detection-->
      ...
      <param name="distanceFromRow" value="0.6" />       

   </node>
</launch>
```

I'm not sure I fully understand your question about roscore on the host. I could have roscore running in its own container instead of on the host, either way I wanted a consistent location for the various ros1 containers and ros1-bridge to access.

I'm not sure what else I can provide, but please let me know and I will do my best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've found a solution from [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3730#issuecomment-233990125).

Adding `tty: true` seems to solve the problem, and the container starts as expected. I assume for some reason the node is waiting on an interactive shell (which docker-compose doesn't provide) and so won't start. I didn't write the node so not super familiar, but I'll have a look and see if anything suggests it would be waiting for a shell.

---

Originally posted by [XDGFX](https://answers.ros.org/users/77679/xdgfx/) with karma: 26 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0